# How can eestrict API only from my android app?

Tags: android, api, security, jwt

I know there are so many similar questions, but I'm confused. 
My purpose is to access my API only from my application. 
 
1) I studied JWT, but I have a doubt. Anyone use my API Login to access my application. get the token and send requests to the server. Right?

0Auth is not for me because I do not use third-party applications. 
 
My idea is to generate a key and one on the server on the client. Then I encrypt the parameters I send (in a certain order) using the client key. Finally on the server I decrypt and make the comparison (since I know the order of the parameters). 
 But the key on the client can be discovered through a reverse

**What do you suggest?**

Comment: Nothing? up....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Problem

> My purpose is to access my API only from my application.

Lets' clear first a usual misconception among developers, that relates to **WHO** vs **WHAT** is accessing the API server.

#### The WHO vs WHAT Is Accessing the API Server

For a better understanding off the difference between **WHO** vs **WHAT** is accessing your API server, I recommend you to read [this section](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) of my article, but I will extract here some lines of it:

> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.
>
> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

So the important bit to get from this is that the user of you mobile app is the **WHO**, not the **WHAT** is accessing your API server.

#### OAuth

> OAuth is not for me because I do not use third-party applications.

You don't need to be using third part applications to use OAuth to authenticate and authorize **WHO** is accessing your API server, by the contrary I would recomend you to use it.

#### JWT Tokens

> 1) I studied JWT, but I have a doubt. Anyone use my API Login to access my application. get the token and send requests to the server. Right?

Yes, anyone(**WHO** and **WHAT**) that grabs your JWT token, or for the matter, any other type of secret you implement to protect access to your API, will be able to use it to pretend to be whatever that secret represents to your API server.

#### Your Idea

> My idea is to generate a key and one on the server on the client. Then I encrypt the parameters I send (in a certain order) using the client key. Finally on the server I decrypt and make the comparison (since I know the order of the parameters).
>   But the key on the client can be discovered through a reverse

Yes, it can be discovered through reverse engineering of the mobile app.

It can be done via static binary analysis with a tool, like the Mobile Security Framework, or at runtime with Frida or Xposed.

> [Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)
>   Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo.

If you are not yet familiar how a secret can be extracted from a mobile app APK with reverse engineering, than you can read the article [How to Extract an API Key from a Mobile App with Static Binary Analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis) to have a better grasp of one of the methods of doing it.

Static binary analysis is not easy to master for extracting secrets that have been hidden in C native code with the use of the JNI/NDK tool set, thus it will be more easy to hook Frida or xPosed at runtime to extract a secret. An attacker will hook into your code in the method that returns the secret, in your case the encryption key, even if it was retrieved from the Android Shared Preferences.

[JNI/NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides):

> Using Android Studio 2.2 and higher, you can use the NDK to compile C and C++ code into a native library and package it into your APK using Gradle, the IDE's integrated build system. Your Java code can then call functions in your native library through the Java Native Interface (JNI) framework.

[Android Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

> A SharedPreferences object points to a file containing key-value pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them. Each SharedPreferences file is managed by the framework and can be private or shared.

You can visit this Github repo [android-hide-secrets](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets) to see a basic Android mobile app, that shows you several ways of hiding a secret, including the JNI/NDK one:

> A quick demo to show several ways of hiding secrets in a mobile app, like in:
>
> - source code
> - manifest file
> - gradle file
> - **JNI/NDK**

To conclude, your idea have merit, but you need to understand that it just makes it hard to bypass, not impossible. So should you use it? Yes, in my opinion we should strive for defense in depth, by applying as many layers as possible, because that will make life of an attacker harder, and even may deter some of proceeding with the attack.

### API Security in Depth

You can start by taking the basic API security measures, followed by some more advanced ones, and if if the data you API is protecting is worth it, you can even employ your own Mobile App Attestation solution.

#### The Basic API Security Defenses

Now that you understand the difference between **who** vs **what** is accessing your API server you may want to go an read [my article](https://dev.to/exadra37/the-top-6-mobile-api-protection-techniques-are-they-enough-3mhn) about basic techniques to secure an API:

> In this article we will explore the most common techniques used to protect an API, including how important it is to use HTTPS to protect the communication channel between mobile app and API, how API keys are used to identify the mobile app on each API request, how user agents, captchas and IP addresses are used for bot mitigation, and finally how user authentication is important for the mobile security and api security. We will discuss each of these techniques and discuss how they impact the business risk profile, i.e. how easy they are get around.

#### More Advanced API Security Defenses

You can start by read this series of articles on [Mobile API Security Techniques](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) to understand how API keys, HMAC, OAUTH and [certificate pinning](https://blog.approov.io/securing-https-with-certificate-pinning-on-android) can be used to enhance the security and at same time how they can be abused/defeated.

Afterwards and depending on your budget and resources you may employ an array of different approaches and techniques to defend your API server, and I will start to enumerate some of the most usual ones.

You can start with [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), followed by [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall)(WAF) and finally if you can afford it a [User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics)(UBA) solution.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

All this solutions work based on a negative identification model, by other words they try their best to differentiate the bad from the good by identifying what is bad, not what is good, thus they are prone to false positives, despite of the advanced technology used by some of them, like machine learning and artificial intelligence.

So you may find yourself more often than not in having to relax how you block the access to the API server in order to not affect the good users. This also means that this solutions require constant monitoring to validate that the false positives are not blocking your legit users and that at same time they are properly keeping at bay the unauthorized ones.

Regarding APIs serving mobile apps a positive identification model can be used by implementing a Mobile App Attestation solution that attests the integrity of your mobile app and device its running on before any request is made to the API server.

#### Mobile App attestation

Finally if you have the resources you can go even further, by building your own [Mobile APP Attestation](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-protect-against-certificate-pinning-bypassing#mobile-app-attestation) solution:

> The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to authenticate what is sending the requests, thus only responding to requests coming from genuine mobile app instances and rejecting all other requests from unauthorized sources.
>
> In order to know what is sending the requests to the API server, a Mobile App Attestation service, at run-time, will identify with high confidence that your mobile app is present, has not been tampered/repackaged, is not running in a rooted device, has not been hooked into by an instrumentation framework(Frida, xPosed, Cydia, etc.), and is not the object of a Man in the Middle Attack (MitM). This is achieved by running an SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device it is running on.
>
> On a successful attestation of the mobile app integrity, a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud know. In the case that attestation fails the JWT token is signed with an incorrect secret. Since the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, it is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the app has been tampered with, is running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is the target of a MitM attack.
>
> The mobile app must send the JWT token in the header of every API request. This allows the API server to only serve requests when it can verify that the JWT token was signed with the shared secret and that it has not expired. All other requests will be refused. In other words a valid JWT token tells the API server that what is making the request is the genuine mobile app uploaded to the Google or Apple store, while an invalid or missing JWT token means that what is making the request is not authorized to do so, because it may be a bot, a repackaged app or an attacker making a MitM attack.
>
> A great benefit of using a Mobile App Attestation service is its proactive and positive authentication model, which does not create false positives, and thus does not block legitimate users while it keeps the bad guys at bay.

### Summary

In my opinion the best solution is defense in depth, by applying as many layers as you can, so that you increase the time, effort and skill-set necessary to by pass all your security layers, thus keeping at bay the script kids and occasionally hackers from abusing your service.

### Going the Extra Mile

I would strongly recommend you, to also take a look into the [OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

Happy coding, and keep secure while at it ;)